# Rename [google-plus-circle] to [google-plus-circles]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Please rename [google-plus-circle](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-plus-circle) to [google-plus-circles](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-plus-circles). This will match other similar tags (e.g., [google-plus-pages](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-plus-pages)).